# Performance issue of WPF application when .NET 4.5 is installed

Tags: wpf, performance, wcf, .net-4.5

We upgraded our development machines and with it, we installed .NET 4.5

Right after that, we noticed our application, which is developed with .NET 4.0 became noticeably slower. This is without touching the source code or what version of .NET the application is compiled against. The problem is, that the application itself is pretty complex and separating possible cause is impossible. The possible causes might include:

- General WPF slowness (not probable)
- Telerik library (same as above)
- WriteableBitmap, which is used heavily even when user doesn't make any actions (yes, SetDirty is used properly)
- WCF used to receive "large" amount (~5kB/s) on constant basis through TCP

I'm asking if there is any relevant information about this issue. I was trying to google, but I only get performance tips and no issue that would fit mine. Right now, the workaround is to uninstall 4.5 and install 4.0, which fixes the performance problem.

Comment: Profile the app. Where is most of the time spent?

Comment: Would strongly recommend taking an ETW trace of the application to troubleshoot (using PerfView is a good start http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out.

In the current code, `Dispatcher.Invoke` is used to synchronize changes from the network queue to the UI. This is called many times per second. To fix this, I used `CompositionTarget.Render` event with double-buffer to push the network queue to the UI and it fixed the performance problems.

It seems that .NET 4.5 did some changes to the `Dispatcher`, so it became a bottleneck in our use case.